# Using Lapack Fortran in eclipse C++ project?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, fortran, lapacke

I've recently inherited a code that makes quite a lot of calls to Lapack functions, with this syntax :

```
F77_NAME(dgemm)(&trans,&trans,&n,&n,&n,&alpha,&D[0][0],&n,&P[0][0],&n,&beta,&temp[0][0],&n);
```

With the following includes :

```
#include <blas.h>
#include <lapacke.h>
```

On windows, and with eclipse CDT, the compilation works fine. I've installed Lapacke with an executable and I have had absolutely no problems with this library.

On Linux (and still with eclipse CDT), however, it's been difficult to say the least. I managed to make the  include works, but I can't seem to do it for . I've managed to include  but the syntax is then wrong and that would be quite long to change it all.

Do you have an idea how I could resolve this ? I've tried various thing, like linking an absolute path, but I can't find blas.h anywhere on my system despite all the libraries I installed through synaptic. Maybe I didn't install the right ones ?

Additionally, I've had some issues with github with this project. To make things short, I started developping on Windows, created the git project from there and went on. When I switched to Linux for testing purpose, I for some reason kept the windows configuration (So C:/Program Files includes, building a .exe ...), I guess I didn't set up the git properly (wouldn't be the first time) but I have no idea how to fix this ... I currently have two different git : one with the Windows configuration and the other with the Linux one .. Not ideal since we're two working on the project.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: _but I can't find blas.h anywhere on my system_: so you have your answer. Install [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)

Comment: You may be interested by [`CBLAS`](http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_cblas), a interface designed to ease calls to fortan functions of BLAS from C/C++. It's just like LAPACKE for LAPACK. See http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/10/31_cblas_clapack_lapacke/ . The header is `cblas.h`. That way, you could get rid of `F77_NAME(dgemm)` which must handle [the different naming conventions between OS](http://www.lacan.upc.edu/doc/intel/compiler_f/main_for/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_procnames.htm). Last : headers may be in developper's package `libblas-dev`.